# php preg_replace multiple backreferences

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use php preg_replace to replace string, but I don't like my solution.

I have:

```
$input = '{@something,param1,param2,param3,paramN}';
$something = 'any string with %3 and %1, then %2 and any more params like %N';
```

I'd like get:

```
$output = 'any string with param3 and param1, then param2 and any more params like paramN';
```

When I have only 3 or less params the following code works, but it's not clean:

```
preg_replace('/\{@'.$someting.',([\$]?[^}]+),([\$]?[^}]+),([\$]?[^}]+)\}/i', 'str_replace(array("%1","%2","%3"),array(\1,\2,\3),"'.$data.'")', $input);
preg_replace('/\{@'.$someting.',([\$]?[^}]+),([\$]?[^}]+)\}/i', 'str_replace(array("%1","%2"),array(\1,\2),"'.$data.'")', $input);
preg_replace('/\{@'.$someting.',([\$]?[^}]+)\}/i', 'str_replace("%1",\1,"'.$data.'")', $input);
```

I'm looking for better solution to join this three lines into one.
I'd like use something like this:

```
preg_replace('/\{@'.$someting.',(PATTERN)\}/i', 'str_replace(array("%1","%2","%N"),array(\1,\2,\N),"'.$data.'")', $input);
```

Comment: This looks like a job for `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: So your input is actually `{@any string with %3 and %1, then %2 and any more params like %N,param1,param2,param3,paramN}`?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking, can you post a sample data about your current text and the output you want?

Comment: I have a text file, where are strings like $input. First word after @ is a defined variable name and words after comma are parameters. Variable is a human readable text with params %N, to replace.